# How Odata can be used in RESTFUL web service, with JSON as the message format

Tags: database, rest, odata

Lets say I have a huge database which stores meta data about music files and (images, sample sound clips and videos in the file systems referring its path in the Db). So how can I implement Odata in this scenario. I would like to present my application as a service to different applications.

Please shed some knowledge. I am stuck with the basic idea of Why, Where to use Odata.

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx

Comment: And here's Netflix implementation: http://developer.netflix.com/docs/oData_Catalog